# iterate through particular column in a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Working in asp.net and c#.

I have a datatable in my application with one column.I want to iterate through that column values and check those values with someother value.please tell me how to do that.I tried it with foreach but its not working.

Code:

```
  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int code = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Code"]);

            if (code == pcode)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else 
            { }
        }
```

**Note:**

**dt** is my datatable with column **code**.I want to compare all values in column **code** with **pcode**.

Comment: You have showed a way, what's wrong with it, what do you actually need?

Comment: **Never** use _"not working"_ on SO! Instead try to explain the wrong behaviour, bug or exception with meaningful words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int code = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Code"]);
```

Although you might want to check for NULL also :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, access dr, instead of dt.Rows[0].

Answer (score 0):

You are always accessing the first row:

```
dt.Rows[0]["Code"]  // use dr instead of dt.Rows[0]
```

> dt is my datatable with column code.I want to compare all values in
>   column code with pcode.

So am i right when i assume that you want to compare all values with one variable, if all fields equal this value, a `bool` variable should be `true`, otherwise `false`?

You can use Linq:

```
var allEqual = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .All(r => r.Field<int>("Code") == pcode);
```

[`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    object o = dr["Code"];
    if (o != DBNull.Value) // Check for null
    {
        int code = Convert.ToInt32(o);

        if (code == pcode)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else 
        { }
    }
}
```